# How could I repair these burnt PCB holes and tracks, after my attempted repair?

Tags: pcb, soldering, heat, repair

I have an Akai mpk mini mkII.  A common problem is a faulty power port, female USB B.

I could not find anybody that knew how to fix it, so I tried myself.  I have never soldered before, so I took a crash course and dove in.  When trying to get the solder out of the through holes, I must have had my heat too high and there for too long because the bigger holes look like they are in much better shape.

Is there any way to restore life back to this PCB? I was told I could try to get the burnt part off, but I am not seeing many resources on how to actually do that.  I'll accept any ideas or assistance you all have to offer, thank you in advance.

[image: ![Photo of burned PCB around holes for USB connector]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xS5e.jpg)

Comment: I would suggest that you find someone close to you who is competent to repair this.  The board is probably salvageable **IF** the right person does the repair.  Be sure to take the replacement connector with you.  FWIW - I've often fixed boards that look like yours.

Comment: ok thanks, how do you often fix boards that look like this?

Comment: clean it first, then take a picture

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to give or send it to someone experienced and ask them to fix it for you, particularly if you want to retain the relatively sturdy USB-B connector.

You've destroyed the through-hole plating and ripped up the pads and traces.

If I was doing it, I would clean it up with alcohol and a knife, inspect it carefully under a microscope, put the new connector in the old position and use fine insulated magnet wire or wire-wrap wire to restore the connections (possibly drilling small holes through the board to get to the other side) and then when it was working, reinforce the damaged mounting pads by putting some epoxy between the connector body and the PCB. But that's relatively skilled work, hard to describe and harder to get right the first time.

Anyway, if you really want to to give it a try, [this guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vvhh-cWpMzI) shows in a video how to bypass the broken socket with a cable.

[image]

Make sure you clean up the old connector footprint with 99% isopropanol and cut off any hanging ripped bits of copper that might short with an Xacto knife or single-edge razor blade. An incorrect connection can easily permanently destroy the board.

Answer (score 2):

You ripped off the pads and some of the traces from this board. You're never going to get another USB connector on that spot and have it work. Best case scenario you could get this to work by tapping those traces elsewhere on the board (if the USB port is only for power this will be simpler) and bodging your own connector on. Maybe you're lucky and you can tap it from an existing pad, but if you need the USB D+/D- traces you're almost definitely going to have to scrape solder mask and bodge a wire on the trace, which can be hard to do even if you have experience soldering. Not entirely beyond saving, but maybe not entirely worth saving at this point.

Comment: seeing as the world is shut down, i dont have anybody to help me work on this other than the good ole internet.  I was already convinced i would have to just get another keyboard but I am for sure looking for any possible solutions.  now how would i go about tapping these traces?

Comment: do you have a multimeter? continuity testing to find good points to tap out with a wire will help greatly

Comment: no I dont but walmart does lol.  do you know of any solid videos that showcase the process of connecting the wire to the board?

Comment: You'll probably want to watch more than one video on the subject, but anyway, here's a skilled guy fixing traces and pads on an old Amiga 600 motherboard. Although it's not exactly the same fix that you're after, there's probably a thing or two to be learned from it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vx50YtEC2S8

Comment: You'll have 4 wires to find, D+, D-, GND and 5V power. They're all going to be necessary for this board to work. It'll also likely be permanently fried if you mix them up and try powering it on anyway. Without the original design files for the board, your best bet is to find the pinout for the original USB connector and use a multimeter to help find a good access point for those nets. Barring that, you'd need to rely on inference and experience. Post a good res image of both sides of the board, in a separate question, and you might be able to lean on some of the collective experience of EE.SE